# "In about two months, my teeth should be perfectly aligned."

Tags: punctuation

1. In about two months, my teeth should be perfectly aligned.
2. My teeth should be perfectly aligned in about two months.

Why is there a comma in the first sentence and not in the second? What is the general rule?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It's [introductory commas](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/commas-after-introductory-phrases/) which are put after an introductory phrase. It's optional, though. If the phrase is short, you can omit the comma.

Comment: Which is to say, there's no rule. You put in the comma when you feel it's a good idea.